# How to get variables expanded in output of jobs command

Tags: zsh, background-process, jobs

As you can see in the following output the variable `$i` in the output of `ps aux` is expanded to `sleep 1`, `sleep 2`, etc.
Is there a way to make `zsh` do the same? In the `jobs` output all the commands get the same name, which is `sleep $i`.

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do sleep $i& done; ps aux | grep sleep; jobs
[6] 1630
[7] 1631
[8] 1632
[9] 1633
[10] 1634
[11] 1635
[12] 1636
[13] 1637
[14] 1638
[15] 1639
root      1630  0.0  0.0   5224   684 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 1
root      1631  0.0  0.0   5224   684 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 2
root      1632  0.0  0.0   5224   744 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 3
root      1633  0.0  0.0   5224   744 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 4
root      1634  0.0  0.0   5224   748 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 5
root      1635  0.0  0.0   5224   752 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 6
root      1636  0.0  0.0   5224   680 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 7
root      1637  0.0  0.0   5224   748 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 8
root      1638  0.0  0.0   5224   748 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 9
root      1639  0.0  0.0   5224   748 pts/3    SN   10:06   0:00 sleep 10
root      1641  0.0  0.0   6144   880 pts/3    S+   10:06   0:00 grep --color=auto sleep
[6]    running    sleep $i
[7]    running    sleep $i
[8]    running    sleep $i
[9]    running    sleep $i
[10]    running    sleep $i
[11]    running    sleep $i
[12]    running    sleep $i
[13]    running    sleep $i
[14]  - running    sleep $i
[15]  + running    sleep $i
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it's not *processes* you put in foreground, but jobs, made of a shell command which could be a compound command starting several processes in parallel (like in `sleep 10 | sleep 20 &`) or one after the other (like in `for i in {1..10}; do sleep $i; done &`).

And each of these process could in turn start more processes (which would still be part of the job, but unknow to `zsh` as not direct descendants) or could change their argument list as reported by `ps` (like in `sh -c 'exec env sleep 10'` which runs a process that executes `sh`, then `env`, then `sleep` all in the same process) or could *leave* the job (by becoming a new process group leader).

It sounds like that for each job, you want to see the arg list of the processes in that job.

Maybe something like:

```
for job state ("${(@kv)jobstates}") {
  pgid=${${state%%=*}##*:}
  echo Job $job:
  pgrep -ag $pgid
}
```

Which on your example gives something like:

```
Job 2:
26590 sleep 1
Job 3:
26591 sleep 2
Job 4:
26592 sleep 3
Job 5:
26593 sleep 4
Job 6:
26594 sleep 5
Job 7:
26595 sleep 6
Job 8:
26596 sleep 7
Job 9:
26597 sleep 8
Job 10:
26598 sleep 9
Job 11:
26599 sleep 10
```

Comment: it's quite a luck that sleep isn't a builtin in `zsh` as in `ksh`.